# Sending struct and nested structed spark columns to ClickHouse through JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, clickhouse

I want to send my spark dataframe to clickhouse table using JDBC.

I have multiple struct columns in my dataframe, structs with struct, array of structs etc.

```
 |-- guest_third_party_id_arr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- source: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

The problem comes when I try to send my data to my clickhouse server using JDBC connection through spark

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for struct<foryou:struct<refreshclick:boolean,removed:boolean>,loved:boolean,loveditems:struct<brandname:string,removed:boolean,undo:boolean>,popular:struct<brandname:string,featuredbrand:boolean,mostloved:boolean,topviewed:boolean>>
```

I want to find a way of sending these structs to my clickhouse. I am not able to find anything online related to this.

I know there is `nested` data type, but there is no doc on how to convert spark struct columns to be compatible to `nested` column type.

I tried https://housepower.github.io/ClickHouse-Native-JDBC/guide/spark_integration.html#integration-with-spark to use their `ClickHouseDialect` but it also does not seem to support struct columns. Does anyone here have any idea on how can I send a spark dataframe containing struct columns to clickhouse, without flattening them.

Comment: can you write as JSON strings? and parse JSON in clickhouse

Comment: That is definitely a pattern we could follow, but we do not want to disturb the query access patterns of analysts as our data currently sits on hive.

Another point is we are doing it for big data, where compressed format for one day contains 500GB, hence we can not to store these columns as json strings and make the analysts do the parsing.